# Show posts from category specified using a custom field

Tags: categories, custom-field, query-posts

I have a post that shows the titles and excerpts from a specific category underneath the content. Currently this is coded into a specific template like this:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=dogs&showposts=5'); if (have_posts()) : ?>
```

This is fine but I need the client to be able to handle this themselves from a generic template so that I don't need to create a new one each time a category is created.

I want the client to create a new post as normal but then use a custom field to pull in posts from a specified category underneath.

For displaying the category name I would use something like this (assume we have a custom field name of "featured" and a value of "dogs":

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured', true); ?>
```

So what I am guessing I need to do is replace the category_name=dogs part of my first example with something that pulls in the meta info.

And that is where my knowledge ends. I know I can post one into the other but I don't know how to resolve it.

Pleeeeeeeeeeeeeeease help!

thanks

James

ps using wordpress 3.2.1 and a custom theme

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it! I needed to add this at the end of each loop :)

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query(array( 'category_name' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured', true), 'posts_per_page' => 5, )); if ($my_query->have_posts()): ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?> content etc goes here
<?php endwhile; ?> <?php endif; ?><?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

many thanks

James

Answer (score 0):

Try to [avoid](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) query_posts:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'category_name'  => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured', true),
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
));

if ($my_query->have_posts()){

   while ($my_query->have_posts()){

     $my_query->the_post();

     the_title();
     the_excerpt(); 
   }

 }
```

Comment: ok I had a look through the codex and worked out what i needed and ended up with the following. The downside is that while it is now displaying posts and there is the correct number its just pulling up the 5 latest and not ones specifically form that category. so I am a bit puzzled!

  `<?php $my_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'category_name'  => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured', true),
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
)); if ($my_query->have_posts()):  ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

content etc goes here

<?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Maybe the requested category name doesn't match the real one? Try capitalizing it with `ucfirst(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured', true))`

Comment: It turned out that a bit further up the page I was using query_posts still and that was interfering (basically there is the article and then one excerpt from one cat and then 5 excerpts from another cat).

But I have found that I can only show the 1 excerpt or the 5 excerpts so i guess the two blocks of code are interfering with each other as the second block always seems to show the latest posts (hope that makes sense)

Comment: Don't use query_posts at all, because it messes up some global variables. Use WP_Query instead; it does the same thing, but without the side effects

Comment: Yeah i have done away with it now. But my two my_query bits of code seem to interfere with each other. any idea how i get round that? thanks for your help!